# How to create flag with or without argument in golang using cobra

Tags: go

As I'm new to golang I want to create flag using cobra package :
Currently my flag is working for below condition :

```
cmd.Flags().StringVarP(&flag, "flag", "f", "", "print names")
```

```
cmd -f "value"
cmd
```

but if I'm using

```
cmd -flag
```

then it is showing below error
flag needs an argument: 'f' in -f

In this case how to handle the situation as I want to all 3 conditions to work?

Answer (score 2):

I created a sample program for your scenario by setting `no option default values for flags` using Cobra.
Please refer this [link](https://github.com/spf13/pflag#usage)

OR

You can also refer this [link](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/issues/909) for other scenarios

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

func main() {

    var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{}
    var flag string
    rootCmd.Flags().StringVarP(&flag, "flag", "f", "yep", "times to echo the input")
    rootCmd.Flags().Lookup("flag").NoOptDefVal = "user"  //use this line
    //rootCmd.Execute()
    err := rootCmd.Execute()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error :", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Output :", flag)
}
```

Output:

```
D:\cobra>go run main.go rootCmd --flag
Output : user

D:\cobra>go run main.go rootCmd --flag=ms
Output : ms

D:\cobra>go run main.go rootCmd          
Output : yep
```

Comment: It's working for me . Thanks for the quick response .
But here I have to pass value without using "="

D:\cobra>go run main.go rootCmd --flag ms
Output : ms

Comment: you can pass it using "=" OR without equal both will work.